# EJB &JPA :throw exception : Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[nju.edu.liushao.cineplex.model.Member#1000001]

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

when programming a EJB program using JPA,an exception never meet:
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-10) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[nju.edu.liushao.cineplex.model.Member#1000001]
22:40:10,896 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-10) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MemberDaoImpl for method public abstract nju.edu.liushao.cineplex.model.Member nju.edu.liushao.cineplex.dao.MemberDao.find(long): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[nju.edu.liushao.cineplex.model.Member#1000001]

codes are as follow:
My JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member")
public class Member implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private long id;
private String password;
private String name;
private int age;
private int gender;
//address of the member
private String province;
private String city;
private String location;
//the time when the member register
private Timestamp registeDate;
//balance of the member's account
private float balance;
//the latest time when the member charge his/her account
private Timestamp chargeDate;
//account state of the member,valid/canceled/suspended
private int state;
private int level;
//total points the member get every time he/she participate an activity
private int points; 

public Member() {
    super();
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(int gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getProvince() {
    return province;
}

public void setProvince(String province) {
    this.province = province;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public Timestamp getRegisteDate() {
    return registeDate;
}

public void setRegisteDate(Timestamp registeDate) {
    this.registeDate = registeDate;
}

public float getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(float balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}



public Timestamp getChargeDate() {
    return chargeDate;
}

public void setChargeDate(Timestamp chargeDate) {
    this.chargeDate = chargeDate;
}

public int getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}
}
```

Comment: and you're presumably doing SOMETHING when this happens ... executing some query maybe? or is that part of the question ... guess what you're doing?

Comment: Also, post the **full** stack trace, as a code snippet to make it readable.